# What do I do with the ground wire?

Tags: grounding, grounding-and-bonding

I just bought a wall timer to replace a three-way switch. The wall timer comes with three wires, one for the common screw wire, and the other two are for the travelers, with no place for a ground wire. When I took out the three-way switch it had the common and the two travelers that I needed and it also has the ground wire.

My question is, where do I put or what should I do with the ground in this situation?

I called the manufacturer and the guy said that "a ground is not needed in this situation and that I should just tape it off". Is that what I should be doing?

Here's a picture of the back of the timer.
[image]

Comment: Where are you installing the switch?

Comment: What country, is what I mean.

Comment: I'm in the United States.

Answer (score 1):

If the switch has no exposed metallic parts after installation—and has no ground terminal—then a ground connection *to the switch* is not needed.  Connect the three ground wires together (one from the power source, and two for the travelers).

If the timer has exposed metal, then there should be a ground screw.  If the junction box it is installed into is metal, ground the box by adding a fourth ground wire into the junction with the other three grounds, and screw the other end of the wire to the j-box.  Use metal screws to install the timer into the j-box:  This grounds the timer and was the standard way of house grounding up until sometime in the 1960s.

If the j-box is not metal, but the timer has some exposed metal, run a ground wire to it and fasten it securely somehow.  (Maybe add link to a photo of the timer for better advice.)

Comment: If the J box is metal, regardless of the switch, it needs to be grounded (in the USA).

Comment: I added a picture in my post.

Comment: @dalutulak:  is the j-box metal?

Comment: @wallyk nope it's plastic